# (xPathHelp) Scrapy not going to next page only scrapes first page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, scrapy-shell

Im trying to extract the nested url in href [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDCkt.png) so I can create a "next page" xpath selector for my spider but I can't figure out the right location path to it.
I've been testing my code in the Scrapy shell environment

Here's my spider source code - using python3

```
import scrapy class StarbucksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'starbucks'
allowed_domains = ['gameflip.com/shop/gift-cards/starbucks']
start_urls = ['https://gameflip.com/shop/gift-cards/starbucks?limit=36&platform=starbucks&accept_currency=USD&status=onsale']

def parse(self, response):
    
    slots = response.xpath('//*[@class="listing-detail view-grid col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2"]')

    for slot in slots:

        fullPrice = slot.xpath('.//*[@class="col-12 description normal"]/text()').extract_first()
        Discount = slot.xpath('.//*[@class="badge badge-success listing-discount"]/text()').extract_first()
        price = slot.xpath('.//*[@class="money"]/text()').extract_first()
        status = slot.xpath('.//*[@alt="sold"]/@alt').extract_first()

        print ('\n')
        print (status)
        print (fullPrice)
        print (Discount)
        print (price)
        print ('\n')

        next_PageUrl = response.xpath('//*[@class="btn"]/@href').extract_first()
        absoulute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_PageUrl)
        yield scrapy.Request(absoulute_next_page_url)
```

Please don't hesitate asking me questions to better assist your answer.
Any help is appreciated ;D

****Thank you** for your time and answers!**

Comment: I think you need selenium or scrapy-splash to extract data. this site using javascript that do not scrape scrapy.

Comment: The website url is using an API to populate the page. You can see the output [here](https://production-gameflip.fingershock.com/api/v1/listing?limit=36&kind=item&category=GIFTCARD&platform=starbucks&status=onsale&sort=_score:desc,shipping_within_days:asc,seller_score:desc,seller_online_until:desc&accept_currency=USD). You can use the `request` and `urllib` libraries to handle fetching. Otherwise what @SamsulIslam said above is how you handle the javascript DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment from `jwjhdev`, the content is coming from an API.
You can see this in the network tab in the dev tools of your browser when reloading the page.
The url of the API can be modified to give you more or less objects per page.
If we increase to `150` in your case, we only get one page of data which means one request: https://production-gameflip.fingershock.com/api/v1/listing?limit=150&kind=item&category=GIFTCARD&platform=starbucks&status=onsale&sort=_score:desc,shipping_within_days:asc,created:desc&accept_currency=USD

So instead of getting the data from the webpage and having to use xpaths, we can query the api and get structured data that is easier to manipulate.

I've modified your spider code slightly below to show how we can get data from the API. We'll use the API url above as one of the `start_urls`
However I noticed that the discount wasn't in the response so I believe that you will have to calculate it in the code.

```
import json
import scrapy


class StarbucksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'starbucks'
    start_urls = [
        'https://production-gameflip.fingershock.com/api/v1/listing?limit=150&kind=item&category=GIFTCARD&platform=starbucks&status=onsale&sort=_score:desc,shipping_within_days:asc,created:desc&accept_currency=USD'
    ]


    def parse(self, response):
        api_data = json.loads(response.text)
        slots = api_data.get('data')

        for slot in slots:
            fullPrice = slot.get('name')
            # I couldn't find in the json the discount
            Discount = 'TODO - Calculate discount using values from API'
            price = slot.get('price')
            status = slot.get('status')

            print('\n')
            print(status)
            print(fullPrice)
            print(Discount)
            print(price)
            print('\n')
```

Comment: Using this method, what is the most common practice used to extract multiple pages rather than just the `start_urls`.  would I have to put multiple API URL's?  Thank you so much for all your help by the way!

Comment: You should play around with the api of the url to try and see how it works. If you remove the platform type (in your case above, the platform was Starbucks), you get cupons from all platforms of the website: https://production-gameflip.fingershock.com/api/v1/listing?limit=150&kind=item&category=GIFTCARD&status=onsale&sort=_score:desc,shipping_within_days:asc,created:desc&accept_currency=USD

Comment: If you only want to scrap lets say: Amazon, Walmart and Starbucks: Use the https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests method and make a request to each platform: `'https://production-gameflip.fingershock.com/api/v1/listing?limit=150&kind=item&category=GIFTCARD&platform={platform}&status=onsale&sort=_score:desc,shipping_within_days:asc,created:desc&accept_currency=USD'.format(platform=my_platform_from_loop)`